# DocuSign API Content Type not supported in multipart message

Tags: php, curl, docusignapi

I'm getting `Content Type specified is not supported. Content-Type for part[0] must be application/json or application/xml` when making a request to add documents to a draft envelope.  As far as I can tell everything looks exactly like their example in the documentation.  But I keep getting this error.  Maybe you can help?  Here's my full request.

```
PUT /restapi/v2/accounts/<int>/envelopes/<string>/documents HTTP/1.1
Host: demo.docusign.net
Accept: application/json
X-DocuSign-Authentication: <personal information excluded>
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=AAA
Content-Length: 23661

--AAA
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Disposition: form-data
{"documents":[{"documentId":"contract-8","name":"contract-8.pdf","order":0}]}
--AAA
Content-Type: application/pdf
Content-Disposition: file; filename="contract-8.pdf"; documentId="contract-8"

<bits for PDF removed>

--AAA--
```

I'm following the documentation [here](https://www.docusign.com/p/RESTAPIGuide/RESTAPIGuide.htm#REST%20API%20References/Add%20Documents%20to%20a%20Draft%20Envelope.htm%3FTocPath%3DREST%2520API%2520References%7C_____53).  And I'm building the request using cURL in PHP.  I'm pretty confident the issue isn't there, but if you're curious I've been building my own library [here](https://github.com/squeegycode/docusign-php) to use with my project.

Thanks again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a newline after the MIME headers, so add a blank line between Content-Disposition: form-data and the { of the json.

Comment: Well that was easy.  I feel dumb for not trying that.  Thanks!